# Way to Get Rails to Log *All* Of Postgres Internals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Is there a way to set sql logging to be *super* verbose in rails?

I have a uniqueness index check on the **primary_key** field of this table that doesn't seem to be working. I'd like to see what postgres is actually doing under the hood a bit more. In other words, I see the INSERT statement, but I'd also like to see a list of the checks it performs before the insert.

```
irb(main):006:0> SampleTable.create(primary_key: 'hi', archived_at: nil)


 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SampleTable Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "sample_tables" ("primary_key", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["primary_key", "hi"], ["created_at", "2019-04-23 12:51:00.295952"], ["updated_at", "2019-04-23 12:51:00.295952"]]
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
=> #<SampleTable id: 2, primary_key: "hi", archived_at: nil, created_at: "2019-04-23 12:51:00", updated_at: "2019-04-23 12:51:00">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about unique index - checks are internal to postgres, rails feeds it an sql query and does not know how it is processed.

But note that `validates :some_field, uniqueness: true` is non-atomic and is prone to race conditions, because between rails' check and actual insert another insert may happen:

1. Request A starts record creation, checks that record with same key is not present
2. Request B starts same procedure and also checks that key is not present
3. Request A proceeds to inserting
4. Request B proceeds to inserting
5. Both requests checked that key was not present, but you have a duplicate in db

This validation should be backed by a unique index on database so that in case of race condition postgres will return error and `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` will be thrown.

Comment: Is there a way to see some kind of console output while the uniqueness indices do their check?

Comment: In the example above, I have a uniqueness index on (primary_key, archived_at), which allows me to duplicate the entry above (SampleTable.create(primary_key: ‘hi’, archived_at: nil) without a ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique being thrown. I know the reason for this is because postgres translates nil to null and, when checking uniqueness, null = null is undefined (rather than true), so you get a primary_key exists = true, but archived at exists = undefined, so (true, undefined) != (true, true), so the insert proceeds.

Comment: If I change the index to primary_key WHERE archived_at IS NOT NULL, ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique *is* thrown because we do a table scan to compare primary_key = primary_key where archived_at is not nil and we get true upon trying to insert the same primary key.

Comment: I just wanted to see the equivalent of a console output of this happening if I could.